# Using pandas.ols on multiple dependent variables at once

Tags: pandas, time-series

I wondering if I can apply the `pandas.ols` model to a data frame of multiple response variables against one independent variable at one time.

So imagine I have the following:

```
In [109]: y=pandas.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,4))
In [110]: x=pandas.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,1))
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
In [111]: model=pandas.ols(y=y, x=x)
```

Basically with the result of four model outputs or at least access to the coefficients of the four. I would prefer to avoid looping through the response variables if possible.

Comment: Do you only need to do OLS with no special standard errors?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it.

```
#First generate the data
x=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,1))
y=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,4))

#Since we are doing things manually we'll need to add the constant term to the x matrix
x[1] = ones(10)

#This matrix precomputes (X'X)^-1X which we will premultiply the y matrix by to get results
tmpmat =  np.dot(np.linalg.pinv(np.dot(x.T ,x)),x.T)

#Solve for the betas
betamatrix = np.dot(tmpmat,y)

#Compare with the pandas output one at a time.
model=pd.ols(y=y[0], x=x, intercept=False)
model=pd.ols(y=y[1], x=x, intercept=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have done this numerous times and have not found an alternative to looping.  Following code will store the results of the the four Regressions in a dict.   If you are only interested in some of the coefficients you can capture them as you loop through the regressions.

```
model = {}
for i in y:
    model[i] = pd.ols(y=y[i], x=x)
```